# PROC SQL IN SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Can you write a code in Proc SQL in SAS  where we have to add a new column named StudentName to Student table which can be blank

Can you provide a example scenario

Like what are the steps to do that in Proc SQL and how to write a code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This site is for asking a specific programming question to get a specific answer.  Your question is too broad of scope to be answered here.  Also you would need to post code you have tried so someone can fix that code.  Otherwise if you are instead needing something from scratch try UpWork or Fivrr or some site that would be able to do that for you.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation AT ALL?  The SQL for that is `ALTER TABLE xxx ADD column`.  https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/sqlproc/n1ckvfae6xf2tyn1nrivm6egpr8b.htm

Comment: Hi I checked but it will be helpful if example can be given as I am new to SAS.As I am trying giving me error.

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Comment: It is giving error like char varchar expected I am writing like this procsql; alter table students add char student name; quit;

Comment: Why would you add an empty variable to an existing dataset? It will just waste time. You will still have to run something else later to populate the new variable, so just add the variable when you actually have values to put in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your question to include the code you provided in comments and the error message that I get when I run that code.

In future, when writing questions on StackOverflow, it is more helpful if you include the full code AND any error messages in your question, that way people can help point out the specific problem and help you understand better.

I must admit the SAS documentation for an entry-level user is not the easiest to follow and the specific page for `ALTER TABLE` does not include any examples. However, I did find some here, in the SAS Docs:

- SAS SQL Procedure User’s Guide

  - Using the SQL Procedure

    - Creating and Updating Tables and Views

      - Altering Columns

        - [Adding a Column](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/sqlproc/p0rdzn3mhqxl2zn13uvxkjkt1svq.htm#n1otfa3gxms1e5n14rdlxe7xo8rk)

So let's look at one of those examples:

```
proc sql;
   alter table sql.newcountries
      add density num label='Population Density' format=6.2;
quit;
```

There's a bit more than you need here, but let's go through each component:

- add - tells PROC SQL you want to add a column
- density - the name of your column
- num - the data type of your column, in SAS this is either (char or num)
- label= - the label for your column
- format= - the format for your column

To update your code, you need to do a couple of things:

- Switch around the variable name and the type
- Update `student name` so it has no spaces, you can do this using an underscore `student_name`

```
proc sql; 
  alter table students add student_name char;
quit;
```

The resulting log:

```
 70           alter table students add student_name char;
 NOTE: Table WORK.STUDENTS has been modified, with 2 columns.
```

The problem you might now encounter is that SAS initialises all columns with a length of 8, so to specify a longer length, use `length=`:

```
proc sql;
  alter table students add long_student_name char length=200;
quit;
```

If you've read this far and this has helped, please remember to bear in mind my tips about including more information in your question - you are far more likely to receive a good quality answer that way.

Comment: Language nit picking. The FORMAT= optional keyword is used to attach a format specification to the variable.  SAS variables do not "have a format". They have a type and a length and you can optionally attach a display format to the variable to use as the default way to display the values.

Comment: Hi thanks one question can you help with this write a sas macro to divide any given table(table name =input table) such a way that each table has 10 rows from the original table (the final table can have <=10 rows)

Comment: @user - write a new question please